# Disable day dynamically after clicking it

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, user-interface, datepicker

I have used the BeforeShowDays method to disable days on page load for my datepicker in the past.
What I would like now is to click on a day, and the day should become disabled (not clickable, as if I used the BeforeShowDays method on that day).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq and don't forget to accept the right answer.. :D cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
var disabledDates = [];
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            disabledDates.push(dateText);
        },
        beforeShowDay: editDays
    });


function editDays(date) {
        for (var i = 0; i < disabledDates.length; i++) {
            if (new Date(disabledDates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {             
                 return [false];
            }
        }
        return [true];
     }
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/QpBmN/)